# Pandas: How to remove/filter Null/Na values?

Tags: python, pandas, null

How can I achieve the following? I want to remove rows (grouped by `id`) if at least there is a NULL in column `inv`.

```
    id  inv   name
0    1  1AB   None
1    1  2CD   Raul
2    1  5DR   Elena
3    2  None  Jose
4    2  None  Ramon
5    2  4RD   Jessi
6    3  3GT    None
7    3  5GR   Alvaro
8    3  6CF   Marge
9    3  45YU   Jim
```

The outcome I am looking for should be like this:

```
    id  inv   name
0    1  1AB   None
1    1  2CD   Raul
2    1  5DR   Elena
6    3  3GT    None
7    3  5GR   Alvaro
8    3  6CF   Marge
9    3  45YU   Jim
```

Comment: Do you mean "if at least there is a **`None`** in column `inv`"?

Comment: Yes, at least a None for each different "id". So this way, considering the example above, "id" number 2 should be filtered or removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the rows where there are Null values, find the unique values for 'id', and then filter the original dataframe to remove any rows in that list of ids.

The syntax would look like this:

```
bad_ids = df[df['inv'].isna()].id.unique()
df[~df['id'].isin(bad_ids)]
```

Comment: Hi, this is incorrect because this would remove only rows will null values but not the rows with values for the same id.

Comment: Sorry about that, misunderstood the question. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I did not use the entire code but the logic was definitely what I was missing.